# Removing Trailing text in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I need to remove text from the end of my URL. The URL will look somthing like the following:

1. www.test.co.za/news/cat/index-mobile.html
2. www.test.co.za/page-name/index-mobile.html

I need to remove the index-mobile.html from the URL.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*)/index-mobile\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# rest of your rules ho here
```